# Select values in SQL Server from XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have this XML:

```
 <SearchResponse>
    <Data>
        <Information>
            <Code>Code 1</Code>
            <Options>
                <Option>
                    <TID>1</TID>
                    <Rooms>
                        <ReturnRoom>
                            <RoomId>1</RoomId>
                            <Description>Single</Description>
                        </ReturnRoom>
                        <ReturnRoom>
                            <RoomId>2</RoomId>
                            <Description>Standard</Description>
                        </ReturnRoom>
                    </Rooms>
                </Option>
                <Option>
                    <TID>2</TID>
                    <Rooms>
                        <ReturnRoom>
                            <RoomId>1</RoomId>
                            <Description>Single</Description>
                        </ReturnRoom>
                    </Rooms>
                </Option>
            </Options>
        </Information>      
    </Data>
</SearchResponse>
```

How I can get

```
Code      Name     TID  RoomId    Description 
---------------------------------------------------
Code 1    Hotel 1   1  1;2     Single;Standard
Code 1    Hotel 1   2   1      Single
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple `nodes` and `value` functions should be sufficient:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'<SearchResponse>
    <Data>
        <Information>
            <Code>Code 1</Code>
            <Options>
                <Option>
                    <TID>1</TID>
                    <Rooms>
                        <ReturnRoom>
                            <RoomId>1</RoomId>
                            <Description>Single</Description>
                        </ReturnRoom>
                        <ReturnRoom>
                            <RoomId>2</RoomId>
                            <Description>Standard</Description>
                        </ReturnRoom>
                    </Rooms>
                </Option>
                <Option>
                    <TID>2</TID>
                    <Rooms>
                        <ReturnRoom>
                            <RoomId>1</RoomId>
                            <Description>Single</Description>
                        </ReturnRoom>
                    </Rooms>
                </Option>
            </Options>
        </Information>      
    </Data>
</SearchResponse>';


SELECT  b.value('(../../../../Code/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Code
       ,b.value('(../../TID/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS TID
       ,b.value('(./RoomId/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS RoomId
       ,b.value('(./Description/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Description
FROM @xml.nodes('/SearchResponse/Data/Information/Options/Option/Rooms/ReturnRoom') AS a(b);
```

**[Rextester demo](http://rextester.com/HPMXWJ69320)**

---

**EDIT:**

If you really need to aggregate string you could use:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT  b.value('(../../../../Code/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Code
       ,b.value('(../../TID/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS TID
       ,b.value('(./RoomId/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS RoomId
       ,b.value('(./Description/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Description
  FROM @xml.nodes('/SearchResponse/Data/Information/Options/Option/Rooms/ReturnRoom') AS a(b)
)
SELECT Code, TID,
      STRING_AGG(RoomId, ';') AS RoomId,
      STRING_AGG(Description, ';') AS Description
FROM cte
GROUP BY Code, TID;
```

This will work for SQL Server 2017+. With lower version you have to use different method like XML or CLR function.

**[DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next&fiddle=74ec0c75727ea7a793c91086b1afc4e2)**

---

**EDIT 2:**

As @Shnugo avoid multiple backward navigation could be avoided by using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT  b.value('(../../Code/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Code
       ,b.value('(TID/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS TID
       ,d.value('(RoomId/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS RoomId
       ,d.value('(Description/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Description
  FROM @xml.nodes('/SearchResponse/Data/Information/Options/Option') AS a(b)
  CROSS APPLY a.b.nodes('Rooms/ReturnRoom') AS c(d)
)
SELECT Code, TID, STRING_AGG (RoomId, ';'), STRING_AGG(Description, ';')
FROM cte
GROUP BY Code, TID;
```

**[DBFiddle 2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next&fiddle=f68c89931e4a8dacb1959376a60d92c3)**

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side, but I'd rather use a call to `.nodes()` down to `<Option>` and an `APPLY` to `.nodes()` down to `<ReturnRooms>`. Backward navigation (like `../../../../Code`) is slow and not very intuitive...